# Find out what JOBQ the RPG program is running on. AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg, job-queue

Is there a way inside an RPG program to find out what JOBQ that program is running on?
I am asking this because there is a program that can be called or submitted and I am interested in saving a log of the timestamp user and jobq that that program had run.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call API QUSRJOBI. Format JOBI0300 has the job queue information. http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/qusrjobi.htm

Comment: Thank you, I did it with that and I could retrieve the information I wanted.